# Householder matrix development

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I follows few YouTube tutorials for householder equation development, one with complex, the other with regular vectors, there are 2 steps that not clear, both of them the same:
For complex vectors:
1- $Px = x-2u^{H}xu$
2- $Px = (I-2uu^{H})x$

For regular:
1- $Px = x-2u\frac{x^{T}u}{u^{T}u}$
2 $Px = (I-\frac{2uu^{T}}{u^{T}u})x$

Which operators need to do in order to get 2 from 1?

Comment: The Householder transformation is usually defined for a unit vector (in either field) so the definitions are essentially the same. It is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat my question: which steps need to do in order to get 2 from 1?

Comment: Note that $(uu^H)x=u(u^Hx)=(u^Hx)u$. Use associativity of matrix multiplication. Also, multiplying a $1\times 1$ matrix is the same as scalar multiplication.